# jquery ajax post email field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure why I'm not able to post the content of email field,

here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        console.log(email),
        $.ajax({
            url: 'db.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'email=' + 'email',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    });

});

</script>
</html>
```

backend file "db.php"

```
 <?php  
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 echo "$email";
```

I'm able to console.log email, and displays correctly, before it gets submitted to db.php.

console log returns "email" only.

Not sure whats wrong, your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to you console.log(data) returning only "email"?  If so, then that is because you are only passing it "email". If you want to have the ajax return the email.val(), then pass the var email to the ajax, not just the string "email".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sending string `"email"`, while you want to send a variable value:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'db.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'email=' + email, // or data: {email: email}
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this it will help

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        console.log(email),
        $.ajax({
            url: 'db.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email: email},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    });

});

</script>
```